# How to ask "India is the seven biggest country in the world" in the form a question?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

I want to ask a question which goes like this:

> India is what biggest nation in the world?

What is the most idiomatic way of asking this question?

Comment: _Seventh_ biggest.

Answer (score 1):

What's India's global ranking in terms of

> population size

> surface area

> number of climate zones spanned

?

Variations: How does India rank in terms of X? How high on the list is India in terms of X? Where's India on the list of Xest countries?